# Optaplanner as jar does not seem to read xml file

Tags: jar, inputstream, filereader, optaplanner

I am new to optaplanner
i worked in iDE and created a working prototype and now want to run in a prod mimic testing.
i created a jar of my entire project
but when i invoke the jar with the input files,
i get exception as "Null POinter Exception"
I tried created SolverFactory by two ways

```
Trial 1:
        SolverFactory<PocSolution> factory = SolverFactory.createFromXmlResource(SOLVER_CONFIG,this.getClass().getClassLoader());
Trial 2:
        SolverFactory<PocSolution> factory = SolverFactory.createFromXmlReader(new FileReader(SOLVER_CONFIG),this.getClass().getClassLoader());

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.kie.internal.io.ResourceFactory.newByteArrayResource(ResourceFactory.java:66)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.AbstractKieModule.getResource(AbstractKieModule.java:299)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.AbstractKieModule.addResourceToCompiler(AbstractKieModule.java:264)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.AbstractKieModule.addResourceToCompiler(AbstractKieModule.java:259)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.AbstractKieProject.buildKnowledgePackages(AbstractKieProject.java:228)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.AbstractKieProject.verify(AbstractKieProject.java:74)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieBuilderImpl.buildKieProject(KieBuilderImpl.java:251)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieBuilderImpl.buildAll(KieBuilderImpl.java:219)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieBuilderImpl.buildAll(KieBuilderImpl.java:177)
    at org.optaplanner.core.config.score.director.ScoreDirectorFactoryConfig.buildDroolsScoreDirectorFactory(ScoreDirectorFactoryConfig.java:503)
    at org.optaplanner.core.config.score.director.ScoreDirectorFactoryConfig.buildScoreDirectorFactory(ScoreDirectorFactoryConfig.java:331)
    at org.optaplanner.core.config.solver.SolverConfig.buildSolver(SolverConfig.java:220)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.AbstractSolverFactory.buildSolver(AbstractSolverFactory.java:57)
    at org.optaplanner.examples.MyPoc.app.Poc.solve(Poc.java:132)
    at org.optaplanner.examples.MyPoc.app.Poc.main(Poc.java:41)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solver config file is being read successfully. The problem seems to be inside the `<scoreDirectorFactory>` element, where you specify score DRL. Please make sure that you use the `<scoreDrl>` element and **not** `<scoreDrlFile>`. `<scoreDrlFile>` is supposed to contain a local file system path whereas `<scoreDrl>` is used to load a classpath resource (which is the case when the DRL file is located inside a JAR). It should look similar to:

```xml
<scoreDirectorFactory>
  <scoreDrl>org/myproj/core/solver/myRules.drl</scoreDrl>
</scoreDirectorFactory>
```